# Subtour constraints formulations for the TSP and Christofide's heuristic

Tags: mathematical-optimization, heuristics, glpk

I am working on the comparison of different formulations of the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP). In particular, I am comparing [DFJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Dantzig-Fulkerson-Johnson_formulation) vs [MTZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Miller-Tucker-Zemlin_formulation) subtour constraint formulation. These are implemented using the GLPK solver (through Python code with the `pyomo` package. Due to the very large number of constraints in the former, the TSP is solved as follows:

1. Relax all subtour constraints
2. solve the MIP
3. if solution is admissible: finish
4. else: add DFJ subtour constraint for every subcycle in the current solution

This is pretty efficient on the instances I need to work on. The MTZ formulation on the other hand is *way* slower (between 10 and 10k times). Therefore I have the following questions:

1. Can the MTZ formulation be efficiently solved iteratively as well?
2. What is the cause of this 10-10k fold increase in time?

Regarding the 2nd question, the two differences are that the DFJ formulation contains $O(2^n)$ subtour constraints whereas MTZ contains $O(n^2)$ subtour constraints and that DFJ works with $n$ variables whereas MTZ works with $2n$. However, since DFJ is solved iteratively, all of the subtour constraints are not needed (actually less than 10 iterations are sufficient for the instances I work with), we are left with a similar number of constraints. Hence, I assume the difference is the number of variables, but I can't figure out why this leads to such a big difference.

As a final note, I figured that using a heuristic method (namely [Christofide's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm)) could yield an upper bound on the objective that can be used as a new constraint (hopefully drastically reducing the set of feasible solutions). However, if I first apply Christofide's heuristic method to have an upper bound on the objective, and then add it to the constraints before solving the MIP, the efficiency is at best unchanged, and at worst decreased up to 10 times.

How come? Is this related to the new shape of the set of feasible solutions? A friend of mine also hypothesized that GLPK might not perform a proper preprocessing in order to remove the dominated constraints, but I don't know if that is true, and I don't know where to look for this.

Does anyone have an idea on one of the numerous questions I have.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the use of Christofides' heuristic: I do not think the right approach is to include its objective as a constraint. Rather, you want to provide the objective as an upper bound to the solver. I am not sure how GLPK handles this, but I would guess there is a way to provide an initial upper bound, which the solver can use to fathom the branch-and-bound tree at first, before it has found a feasible solution that is better than your bound.

Also, Christofides has nice theoretical properties, but it is not, in general, the best heuristic out there for TSP. Even some really simple ones like farthest insertion perform better on average.

Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions about DFJ vs. MTZ subtour elimination constraints...